# VBA: Command button updating Excel sheet based on Listbox contents

Tags: vba, excel

If a name appears in Listbox2, i need to search a sheet with any matching names and update column 9 from 0 to 1. Currently, the code i have nearly works, but does not account for names that appear more than 1 time in the sheet. So only the first time a name appears in the sheet, does column 9 update from 0 to 1.

Below is the code im using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Dim i As Integer
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = Sheet1

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
ListBox2.Selected(i) = True

rw = wks.Cells.Find(What:=Me.ListBox2.List(i), SearchOrder:=xlRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
wks.Cells(rw, 9).Value = "1"

Next i

Sheet3.Shapes("Button 3").Visible = Sheet1.Cells(1, 26) > "0"
MsgBox ("Update Successful")
Me.Hide
ListBox2.Clear 
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll


End Sub
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: are the _names_ to be searched in one columns only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Find in this way to look for something which occurs more than once. You store the address of the first found cell, and then loop until you return to this cell which tells you that you've found all instances. When using Find it's also worth checking first that your value is found - your code would error if the term were not found.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

Dim i As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet, r As Range, s As String

Set wks = Sheet1

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    ListBox2.Selected(i) = True
    Set r = wks.Cells.Find(What:=Me.ListBox2.List(i), SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        s = r.Address
        Do
            wks.Cells(r.Row, 9).Value = 1
            Set r = wks.Cells.FindNext(r)
        Loop Until r.Address = s
    End If

Next i

Sheet3.Shapes("Button 3").Visible = Sheet1.Cells(1, 26) > "0"
MsgBox ("Update Successful")
Me.Hide
ListBox2.Clear
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Comment: Good names help future readability, too.  `s` -> `firstAddress`, `r` -> `foundRange`, etc...

Comment: Indeed. Personally I don't like long variable names, but I agree that they are advisable.